# MySQL: Select row where column contains element from list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select all rows from a table where column contains an element from a list:
Something like

```
Select * from `table` where `column` (contains anything from {£,$,%,^,&,...,/})
```

This is basically an illegal character check.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For MySQL you may use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) or [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) to check specific column for pattern matching. In your case following example might work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP '[\£\$\%\^\&]';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know of an escape sequence for *? I want this as an illegal character too, struggling to find anything on it

Comment: Escape everything with backslash. Result: `[\£\$\%\^\&\*\?]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` for pattern matching,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `table`
WHERE   `column` LIKE '%£%' OR
        `column` LIKE '%$%' OR
        `column` LIKE '%\%%' OR
        `column` LIKE '%&%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly you want all rows which have non alphanumeric characters ie other than digits and alphabets

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
```

The `^` inside `[ ]` charcter class implies negation while outside at the beginning of regular expression specifies starting of column value. `$` imples ending of string value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%\%%' OR column LIKE '%$%' OR column LIKE '%&%';
```

...etc. '%char%' means that there is char somewhere, '%char' means that char is at the end of string, 'char%' means that it is at the beginning. '%\%%' means that searched char (%) is a special char used by mysql and '\' is necessary.